# Bash convert to pdf

Tags: bash

How can I use both ls and convert to transform all images files in a directory to a pdf ?
Also I need to put the files in a certain order for example files like AA1.png,AA11.png need to respect this logical order.

Update (ls) and (convert) are available , but how can I used them together ?

Comment: Do you mean separate PDFs or a single PDF?

Answer (score 13):

To convert to a single PDF can be done in a single command:

```
convert -compress jpeg *.jpg my-jpegs.pdf
```

Remember to include the `-compress jpeg` flag, or it'll store the images uncompressed and result in a massive PDF.

ImageMagick (via convert) requires Ghostscript (gs) to be installed in order to process PDFs I believe.  Beware of memory issues if you are adding a lot of JPEGs at once.

As for your logical ordering, you can use `ls` in combination with `convert` to get the list in order.

Something along the lines of:

```
convert -compress jpeg `ls *.png` my-jpegs.pdf
```

See `ls --help` for the various sorting options available.

Comment: Good tip, but the sort order is the problem.

Comment: Right, I've added more for your sorting issue.

Comment: The `ls` in backticks is not doing anything useful by itself.  If you add a useful sorting option, it might be warranted, though.

Comment: @tripleee: I did state the need for a sorting option and how to go about finding them in the answer.

Comment: ImageMagick needlessly decodes and re-encodes the JPEG data, resulting in generation loss and poor performance.

Comment: @RobertFleming: Quite right, PDF files can have JPEGs embedded within them - so better to not convert if possible.  Really, ImageMagick should handle that directly if there are no operations other than the conversion.

Answer (score 6):

https://gitlab.mister-muffin.de/josch/img2pdf

In all of the proposed solutions involving ImageMagick (i.e. `convert`), the JPEG data gets fully decoded and re-encoded. This results in [generation loss](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generation_loss), as well as performance "ten to hundred" times worse than img2pdf.

Comment: I cannot see a license on this code.  Did you write it yourself?  Is it MIT, GPL, etc?

Comment: I didn't write that. Its author's e-mail address is hidden in his test_comp.sh if you want to contact him.

Comment: Not particularly, just thought it is unusable generally without a license.  Which is a shame, as it's no doubt useful.

Comment: Author of img2pdf here - I added a license a while ago but forgot to push my changes :)

You can now see that it is released under the terms of GPL3+. I didnt think it would ever be useful for anybody which explains the long lack of a license.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a lot of files:

```
convert -limit memory 1 -limit map 1 *.jpg foo.pdf
```

[see here](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=12623)

or with compression

```
convert -limit memory 1 -limit map 1 -compress jpeg -quality 85 *.jpg foo.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for image in `ls *.png`; do
  # call convert or whatever here
  convert $image `basename $image .png`.pdf
done
```

Comment: I need a single pdf file with all images order by name ( logical order image1.png,image2.png,...image11.png)

Comment: The `ls` in backticks is an antipattern.  `for image in *.png; do ...` is both simpler and more correct.